# Find quickly index of item in sorted list

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have a object:

```
public class MyObject
{
int id;
string value;
}
```

I also have a list:

```
List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>;
for(int i=0;i;i<100000;i++)
{
list.Add(new MyObject(i, string.Format("Item {0}", i));
}
```

And list will be:

```
1, "Item 1"
2, "Item 2"
....
99999, "Item 99999"
```

This list is a sorted list which sorted on ID field. Note this is an example to describe a sorted list, it is not simple like the above example.

I want to find a item of ordered list based on ID field. I don't know .NET Framework has support quickly search on a ordered list without enumerating.

**I am interested in performance because of a big list. Thanks.**

Best regards.

Comment: No, your list will start with `0, "Item 0"`

Comment: Yes, list will begin with 0, "Item 0" but what you mean? This list is only an example to describe a ordered list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) for this.

You can use the [built-in implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftfdbfx6.aspx), providing a custom [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) that compares on your type's `id` property:

```
var objToFind = new MyObject { id = 42 };

int foundIndex = yourList.BinarySearch(objToFind, new MyObjectIdComparer());

// ...

public class MyObjectIdComparer : Comparer<MyObject>
{
    public override int Compare(MyObject x, MyObject y)
    {
        // argument checking etc removed for brevity

        return x.id.CompareTo(y.id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Four options:

- If your list will *always* contain items with ID 1...n, then you can just do:

  ```
  MyObject foo = list[id - 1];
  ```
- You could populate a `Dictionary<int, MyObject>`
- You could make `MyObject` implement `IComparable<T>` or `IComparable` (ordering by ID) and use `List<T>.BinarySearch`, providing a dummy `MyObject` with the desired ID
- You could implement binary searching yourself - it's not terribly hard to do so

Note that if you take the last approach, you *may* want to do so in a generic way as an extension method so that you can reuse it later:

```
// Optionally another overload with an IComparer<TKey>
public static TItem ProjectedBinarySearch<TItem, TKey>(
    this IList<TItem> list,
    Func<TItem, TKey> projection)
{
    // Do the binary search here.
    // TODO: Decide what to do if you can't find the right value... throw
    // an exception? Change the return type to return the *index* instead of the
    // value?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume it won't actually be 1:1 with array index and ID field (like in your example), or you could just use the []-method to find it.

Option 1 would be to add it to a Dictionary instead, and use ID field as key.

Option 2 is to write a makeshift binary search, starting at the middle of the array and checking if the current id is larger, smaller or correct. Then doing it again with the new sub-array until you find your ID.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a brute force, start-end, search, you could implement some kind of binary division and that should speed it up nicely. Or use the Dictionary type instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use .Find() to find an item in a list, without explicitely enumerating:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx

EDIT: Actually, looking in more detail it looks like this is a linear search and might not be what you want.

Comment: That's still going to be O(N) though. It's still enumerating, just not explicitly.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that after I posted it, doh!

Answer (score 0):

The index regarding you `ID` is `ID - 1`. However, if you have deleted items, that way will no work. You can then use `Binary search`, PROVIDED that you list is sorted. So you have to keep it always sorted, or you will use uneffecient `Linear search`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Linq

```
using System.Linq;
```

Obtain a queryable from your list (usually via .AsQueryable() call)

Apply a .Select() on obtained Queryable

```
var c = queryable.Select (x => x.field == 999)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those people who have come across this question based on it's title (Find quickly index of item in sorted list) you may be interested to know that SortedList< TKey, TValue> has the following two methods:-

```
    public int IndexOfKey(TKey key);
    public int IndexOfValue(TValue value);
```

and SortedList has:-

```
    public virtual int IndexOfKey(object key);
    public virtual int IndexOfValue(object value);
```